# timeout para $http request (buscar por 5 segundos, se não achar, retorna 'erro')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, timeout

Estou configurando um $http request para CEP, acontece que as vezes a API demora demais para devolver uma resposta, e o usuário fica travado de prosseguir no checkout.

a função funcionava, mas quando tentei adicionar o timeout ela parou.

**FUNÇÃO:**

```
  if(this.cep && this.cep.length > 7) {
    // Conneting API to get CEP Values
    $http.get(`${API_URL}/carriers/correios/get-cep/${this.cep}`)
    .timeout(500, () => {
      .success((address) => {
        this.CEPloading = false;
        this.CEPerror = false;
        this.validCEP = true;

        updateShippingPrice(address.uf);
        updatePrice();

        this.bairro = address.bairro;
        this.cidade = address.cidade;
        this.endereco = address.end;
        this.uf = address.uf;

        updatePrice();
      })
      .error(() => {
        this.CEPloading = false;
        this.CEPerror = true;
      });
    })

  }
```

Comment: Mas a função `.timeout` é para encerrar certo, obviamente que quando ele terminar de ler esses `500`, ele irá parar de funcionar, se não houver um ***refresh*** antes dessa execução acabar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

de acordo com o site do angularJS.

utilizar um configurador p/ o http.

exemplo a baixo.

```
$scope.method = 'GET';
$scope.url = ${API_URL}/carriers/correios/get-cep/${this.cep};
$scope.timeout = 10000; (miliseconds);

$http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache:false, timeout = $scope.timeout}).then(function(response) {
          $scope.status = response.status;
          $scope.data = response.data;
        }, function(response) {
          $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = response.status;
      });
```

referência: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: foi o que eu fiz, e funcionou, valeu !